# Two Spinner menu items in ActionBar width

Tags: android, width, android-actionbar, spinner, menuitem

I've manually built two spinners in the Action bar, by creating at first two menu items in the main.xml file. With the line

```
cSpinner.setAdapter( ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this,
            R.array.category_data,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item )
            );
```

I set the Array Resource for them.
These things actually work but the problem is, that the left spinners resource string is so big that just a small bit of the right spinner can be seen.

[image]

I've tried things like `cSpinner.setLayoutParams(new Spinner.LayoutParams(60, 20));` or '

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = pView.getLayoutParams();
         params.width = 100;
            cspinner.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But none of them work. The second one even lets the program crash.
Do you now know a tip how I can solve this problem?

Comment: try setting the values inside the spinner's layout file.

Comment: The two spinners aren't actually spinners in the layout.xml file, they are two menu items in menu.xml so I can't set values to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for this you have to add custom Layout in ActionBar like Below

[image]

[image]

---

code is here

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final String[] choices = { "Android", "iOS", "RIM" };

    private Spinner Spin1;
    private Spinner Spin2;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                choices);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_item);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        Spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        Spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
        Spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

---

actionbar_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="my App name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, exactly the thing I was looking for.

Comment: not understand WHY actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_item); and before this u can use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);